# How to fix javadoc for Google Play Services in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, google-play-services, google-play-games

I have integrated Google Play Games by adding this dependency to my build.gradle:

`implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-games:22.0.1'`

The correct javadoc .jar file seems to be attached to the Google Play libraries in Android Studio (I checked in `Project > External libraries > Library properties`)

On my PC it's a valid file located at `C:\Users\myusername\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.android.gms\play-services-games\22.0.1\9f45822a5bacdc3094d84a49cdbf48bbac45f738\play-services-games-22.0.1-javadoc.jar`

Yet the documentation works correctly on some code...
[image]

...but fails on most methods:
[image]

AS states that `The following documentation urls were checked: ...`

**How can this be fixed?**

Comment: @Viewed not really.